# How can outdated packages be listed with the pkg command in FreeBSD?

Tags: package, freebsd

I must be too stupid for searching. I can't find a way to list all outdated installed packages against the current ports tree. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've found, what I was looking for here in the FreeBSD pkg primer:

https://wiki.freebsd.org/PkgPrimer

show out of date packages (determine out of the ports tree):
**pkg version -l <**